# Nginx HttpGeoIPModule with X_Forwarded and HAProxy

Tags: nginx, haproxy, geoip

Is it possible to make Nginx HttpGeoIPModule use the X_Forwarded IP that is sent via HAProxy? It is currently just using the incorrect server IP, but unsure how I can make Nginx use the X_Forwarded IP.

Any ideas?

Comment: James, just for clarification, are you seeing the X-Forwarded-For ip address in nginx's access log and the geoip module still uses the proxy's address ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the RealIPModule and setting the X-Real-IP to X-Forwarded-For

You have to pass --with-http_realip_module during compile time to build the module because it is not built by default.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRealIpModule

Comment: If you read my question, I am already doing this and I am asking whether I can make HttpGeoIPModule obey this. It does not at the moment.

Comment: James, is this working for you?  I see the expected working behavior with my install of nginx (1.0.5) with RealIPModule and GeoIPModule.

Comment: James, you want to you the X-forwarded-for IP to do a Geo lookup right? When you get the X-Real-ip to X-forwarded-for IP geoIP will work. You can refer to this forum post. Similar question. http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?10,220550,220550

Answer (score 1):

Sameer's answer is correct.

You'll need to configure and compile Nginx with the --with-http_realip_module option.

Then set the following option in the Nginx configuration:

`set_real_ip_from 1.2.3.4;`

`real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;`

Where 1.2.3.4 is the IP Address of HAProxy

In HAProxy you'll need the following options:

`option httpclose`

`option forwardfor`

I found this website helpful: http://www.somerorbay.com/vps-and-dedicated/nginx-behind-haproxy-x-forwarded-for-getting-real-client-ip

Comment: If you read my question, I am already doing this and I am asking whether I can make HttpGeoIPModule obey this. It does not at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to run HA Proxy in transparent mode, then all IPs will display correctly. Usually a little IP Tables 'mangling' is needed to make it work, but well worth the effort.